# Притяжательное прилагательное от имени Виталик

Tags: ономастика, прилагательные

Мои родственники, рассуждая о младшем брате, без конца употребляют прилагательное *Виталикин, Виталикина*. Лично мне это режет слух; правильнее было бы сказать *Виталькин*, но мы зовём брата исключительно Виталиком. Согласно нормам словообразования, следует говорить *Виталиков*, но — произнесите сами — как-то непривычно звучит. Может быть, от этого имени вообще нельзя образовать прилагательное? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Виталькин отлично звучит, на мой взгляд, но это производное не от Витал**ика**, а от Виталь**ки**.

Comment: @Артём Луговой, ну, известное дело. Я же затем и указала, что брата в моей семье принято называть Виталиком, а вовсе не Виталькой, и *Виталькин* мне не пойдёт.

Comment: Действительно, написали! Не уловил всего как следует. ;)

Answer (score 1):

У нас в семье слово *Виталикин* тоже в ходу, но насколько это корректно?

В Нацкопрпусе нашлось слово *Виталиков*, но только у одного автора, а слова *Виталикин* нет вообще.

Тогда бы его, **Виталиков**, пищевой бизнес процветал. [Михаил Дерюгин. Библиотекарь (1997) // «Столица», 1997.02.17]

А недавно Петька, шофер **Виталиков**, мне рассказал: «Едем как-то с работы. [Михаил Дерюгин. Библиотекарь (1997) // «Столица», 1997.02.17]

Comment: Вот я и думаю, лучше уж говорить *Виталика*: книга Виталика, карандаш Виталика. Но подожду, вдруг ещё кто-нибудь из участников сообщества отпишется. Насчёт прилагательных *Виталикин* и *Виталиков* — моя душа протестует. Особенно против первого, второе ещё можно объяснить, моя неприязнь к нему субъективна.

Comment: Ольга, слово образовано правильно и само по себе звучит нормально. Но если возникает желание украсить им речь или текст, нужно считаться с тем, что а) в ряде контекстов оно может выражать иронию и б) может вызывать ассоциацию с фамилией и соответствующее недопонимание при быстром прочтении, например, в первой цитате из данного ответа "Виталиков" может восприниматься как обращение по фамилии, во втором можно подумать, что упомянут "шофёр Петька Виталиков" (поэтому лучше было бы "Виталиков шофёр").

Comment: P.S. Таких недоразумений не возникает в сочетаниях "Виталиковы сапоги", "Виталиково полотенце" и т. п., хотя этот приём и придаёт книжно-старомодную окраску соотв. высказываниям.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, устроит ли, но кое-что нашлось (в подтверждение *правильности **Виталиков***):

*Ночью я несколько раз просыпался. Мне снился хохочущий **Виталиков** дед, кладбище и какие-то покойники.*
[**Летний отдых**](http://www.strashilka.com/witch/18266-summer-holiday.html)

*– Так ты работаешь, Виталий Райхман? – широко улыбнувшись, спросил **Виталиков** личный спецназовец.*
[**Третья стена**](https://ficbook.net/readfic/2874688/7789615)

*Результат был нулевой. Тогда она достала мобильник и набрала **Виталиков** номер.*
[**Кукла**](https://alisa-mun-kukla.livejournal.com/)

*Стекло левой задней дверцы чуть приопустилось, и там показалась камера — **Виталиков** верный оператор уже снимал первые кадры, милицейские машины, зевак, дом.*
[**Сокровище антиквара**](http://book-online.com.ua/read.php?book=2933&page=65)

Comment: @Ольга Если необходимы ссылки — "изображу".

Answer (score 0):

> Мои родственники, рассуждая о младшем брате, без конца употребляют
>   прилагательное *Виталикин, Виталикина*. Лично мне это режет слух...

Но родственникам-то Вашим не режет… А потому –  смиритесь.

Ничего неправильного в прилагательном *Виталикин* нет. И говорят так не только Ваши родственники.

Слово встречается у многих авторов. Есть и в Нацкорпусе:

*И по **Виталикиному** лицу поняла, что сморозила глупость.* [Ольга Некрасова. Платит последний (2000)]

Comment: Вопрос: а можно ли доверять этим авторам?

Comment: Вы как писали слово: Виталик или Виталикин? Я в поиске ***Виталикин*** не нашел.

Comment: _Серж: Вопрос: а можно ли доверять этим авторам?_ === А у меня встречный вопрос: а в чём некорректность-то такого прилагательного?

Comment: _Серж: Я в поиске **Виталикин** не нашел._ === А в какой строке Вы набирали это слово?

Comment: Суффикс -ов, -ев, производящий имена прилагательные от существительных мужского рода на твердый и мягкий согласный и очень редко— в просторечии— от существительных среднего рода и выражающий принадлежность одному определенному (обозначенному основой имен существительных) существу, в книжных стилях литературного языка угасает.

Comment: В строке "Поиск".

Comment: Другой притяжательный суффикс -ин образует краткие прилагательные от названий лиц и животных с окончанием на -а, -я (и реже от слов женского рода на мягкий согласный с нулевым окончанием в именительном падеже): мамин, тетин, дядин, кошкин, курицын, свекровин и т.п.

Comment: _Серж: В строке "Поиск"._ === Наберите в строке "Слово" в разделе "Лексико-грамматический поиск".

Comment: Ну так дайте ссылку — во избежание споров (или обременительно?).

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Ну так дайте ссылку — во избежание споров (или обременительно?)._ === Это мне? По-моему, никакого спора с Сержем у меня не было. Я лишь пытался объяснить ему, как пользоваться Нацкорпусом. А если Вам нужна ссылка -- пожалуйста: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%E8%F2%E0%EB%E8%EA%E8%ED&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Comment: Я бестолковая, наверное: понятия не имею — что такое _нацкорпус_?  Никогда _оттуда_ информацией не пользовалась: только просматривала в _чужих_ ответах.

Comment: slava1947, выходит, оба варианта можно считать корректными?

Comment: На а почему бы и нет? Кто-то, как у Вас в семье, говорит _Виталикин_, кто-то, в другой семье, использует другую форму... На имена и производные от них стандарты не нацепишь.

Comment: Согласна с Сержем. Во всём. Про суффиксы второй раз объяснять не буду; скажем проще — прилагательное *Виталикин* наталкивает на мысль, что имя — Виталика, а не Виталик. Насчёт авторов — я не стала бы доверять ОДНОМУ автору, употребившему это слово, тем более что многие современные писатели на редкость безграмотны. «*На имена и производные от них стандарты не нацепишь*». Ещё как *нацепишь*, если знать, какие суффиксы присоединяются к слову с нулевым окончанием и основой, оканчивающейся на твёрдую согласную.